# Extending class with static fields for the purpose of "overriding" static properties

Tags: java, spring, software-design

This is posing a heated debate and I would like to know if there are any problems with this approach.

I have a class which contains nothing but static strings:

```
public class EventConstants {
    public static ID = "1";
    public static DOMAIN = "local";
    public static final DEVICE = "PC";
    public static final SOURCE = "local";
}
```

Now the reason ID and DOMAIN are not `final` is because I have chosen to override them given Spring `ConfigurationProperties`.  So...

```
public CustomEventConstanstants extends EventConstants {

    @Autowired
    private PropertyMapper mapper;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ID = (mapper.ID != null) ? mapper.ID : EventConstants.ID
        DOMAIN = (mapper.DOMAIN != null) ? mapper.DOMAIN : EventConstants.DOMAIN
    }
}
```

The idea behind this class is the user can simply call one class and use the appropriate constant as configured by a Spring property or not.
Example:

```
object.methodA(CustomEventConstants.ID)  // This will return the configured ID or what's in EventConstants
object.methodB(CustomEventConstants.DEVICE)
```

The argument I'm having is other's believe it is not appropriate for testing since it cannot be appropriately Mocked out.

Comment: Just use a default environment and then different environment properties which override the default one

Comment: You don't need a `Properties` instance here, just refer to it as `Properties.ID`, `Properties.DOMAIN` etc. You would get any "overridden" values anyway, since static members are not polymorphic.

Comment: @AndyTurner My mistake - huge error in class name.  I edited the code, I was being terse and forgot about the `Properties` class.  I updated it to our own `PropertyMapper` which is our Spring configuration.

Comment: @Lino Can you explain your comment a little more.  Won't I still need to make this a Bean?

Comment: What can't be mocked out, and why not?

Comment: @DaveNewton Well, this class (or at least EventConstants), was being used throughout a number of tests in a couple of other projects. I was tasked with extending it with this flexibility yet not really impacting the resting of the existing code base.  When testing the other projects, the will now have to enable a SpringContext (even if they didn't need one) and go through the process of Mocking out this class.

Comment: You could have an intermediary class taking a mapper in its ctor: in the Spring version you can wire a mapper via annotations but use that mapper to instantiate the intermediary class. In non-Spring codebases you use only the intermediary class and construct it however you want.

Comment: @DaveNewton Not a bad idea.  I think they are just annoyed they want to do any more work :)